# How to install matplotlib for particular version of Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed scipy and numpy, and they are being used with my current, desired version of python 2.7.6 (I am running on OSX Mavericks and had to upgrade.) However, when I `pip` installed matplotlib, by default it referenced my previous python version, 2.7.5, thus making it troublesome to use (obviously.)

How do I change which version of python matplotlib uses so I can import and use the library? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would solve this problem is like this, firstly one would need to go into your 2.7.6 directory, and under the `Scripts` folder you will find the `pip` executable. My *suggestion* is (because its difficult to debug this kind of people without having all the details) is this:

```
./pip install matplotlib
```

And see if this succeeds, otherwise, I suggest using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to manage your python installations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Macports for installing additional Python versions on OS X. Once Macports is installed, it's fairly easy to install Python 2.7.6. All you'd have to do is:

```
sudo port install python27
```

Now, you should be able to get all the libraries you need just as easily, using, too, Macports.

```
sudo port install py27-numpy
sudo port install py27-scipy
sudo port install py27-matplotlib
```

Macports should solve all the dependencies and, of course, link the packages to their correct Python versions, avoiding you a lot of headaches.

For a step by step guide on how to set up a nice, functional Python environment, visit: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/02/02/setting-up-a-mac-for-python-development/